# bootstrap picker format with comma causing random issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

When using the picker [demo link](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) add the format like this M d, yyyy to the format field. 
Open the picker. select a date. hit any key on the keyboard example command key on a mac and it will remove the active day and select a random day. Click anywhere to close the picker it will append the date to the already added date in the input field. This creates multiple values in the input field.

Any way around this happening ?

Comment: Please use [tag:twitter-bootstrap] instead of [tag:bootstrap].

Comment: twitter-bootstrap has a date picker ?

Comment: No. But the [tag:bootstrap] tag is not meant to be used for the Twitter bootstrap library.